# How to create minify JS with this document

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify

I'm trying grunt uglify to minify a JavaScript file with a document, like below:

JS:

```
var _html = (function(){/*<div id="test_id">...</div>*/}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/;?\}$/)[1];
html = _html....
```

In order to maintain and change this easily, I'd like to remain here document. However, after I use grunt uglify, this document has been removed, and create DOM objects. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this prob.

I do

```
var _html = "{% html_macro %}";
```

and write down template replace.

```
replace: {
    // default
    dev: {
        src : ['target.js'],
        overwrite: true,
        replacements: [{
            from: '"{% html_macro %}"',
            to: _html
        }]
    }
},
```